# Can't recored a video using com.commonsware.cwac:cam2

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using Android Studio and run AVD emulator (Nexus 5X API 25, Android 7.1.1 with Google APIs).

The project is a demo one, from https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/releases/download/v7.0/RuntimePermTutorial.zip

When I press Record Video button (the green one), the video freezes and nothing happens however the settings button is active and actually 'defreezes' the video, but the only way to exit recording mode is the BACK button.

I tried it with emulators on API 23 and 24 and didn't see the same issue.

Does API 25 system require some additional setup for video?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not know of anything needed for API Level 25. At the same time, I don't advertise support for emulators. I will try to peek at this next week, but I make no promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the built-in Camera app on the 7.1 emulator has similar issues, and since the problem is limited to that emulator, I am going to consider this an emulator issue. For 7.1, test on hardware. Ideally, for all versions of Android, test on hardware.